# Cookiecutter : jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: expected token 'end of print statement', got ':'

Tags: python-3.x, cookiecutter

I am trying to learn how to use cookiecutter and have created my own django based project that contains some static jinja2 templates referencing .js, .map files.

I have created and adapted this from a working local project that successfully displays a webapp when running `python manage.py runserver`.

However, when I try to run my cookie-project I get a `jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: expected token 'end of print statement', got ':'` for a third party `js.min.js.map` file as listed below:

It is as though cookiecutter is trying to parse the *map* file?? Shouldn't cookiecutter copy the static files across to the new project? How can I debug why this is happening?

**error raised when I try to use my cookie cutter project**

```sh
$ cookiecutter my-cookiecutter-project

description [desc]: desc
email [me@example.com]: 
full_name [Your Name]: me
license [MIT]: 
project_name [default_project]: myproj
python_version [3.8]: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/simon/Library/Python/3.8/bin/cookiecutter", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/Users/simon/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1137, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/simon/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1062, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "/Users/simon/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1404, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "/Users/simon/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/click/core.py", line 763, in invoke
    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/simon/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/cookiecutter/cli.py", line 140, in main
    cookiecutter(
  File "/Users/simon/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/cookiecutter/main.py", line 101, in cookiecutter
    result = generate_files(
  File "/Users/simon/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/cookiecutter/generate.py", line 352, in generate_files
    generate_file(
  File "/Users/simon/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/cookiecutter/generate.py", line 169, in generate_file
    tmpl = env.get_template(infile_fwd_slashes)
  File "/Users/simon/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 997, in get_template
    return self._load_template(name, globals)
  File "/Users/simon/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 958, in _load_template
    template = self.loader.load(self, name, self.make_globals(globals))
  File "/Users/simon/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/jinja2/loaders.py", line 137, in load
    code = environment.compile(source, name, filename)
  File "/Users/simon/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 757, in compile
    self.handle_exception(source=source_hint)
  File "/Users/simon/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 925, in handle_exception
    raise rewrite_traceback_stack(source=source)
  File "./{{ cookiecutter.project_name }}/local/api/static/assets/plugins/chartist-js/dist/chartist.min.js.map", line 1, in template
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: expected token 'end of print statement', got ':'
```

Answer (score 2):

Solved it! The problem was that cookiecutter was trying to render the jinja2 templates during copy operation.

As stated [here](https://cookiecutter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/copy_without_render.html) there is an option to copy and not render jinja2 templates.

So...I updated my `cookiecutter.json` to:

```json
{
  "description": "desc",
  "email": "me@example.com",
  "full_name": "Your Name",
  "license": "MIT",
  "project_name": "default_project",
  "python_version": "3.8",
   "_copy_without_render": [
        "*.html",
        "*.js",
        "*.map",
        "*.css"
   ]
}
```

Now it is working!